# Show thumbnail at end of youtube video

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api

I'm working on mobile device. (iOS)

I have a thumbnail for my Youtube video. On click, it disapears and auto-play my video in an iframe (fullscreen on mobile). It works great .

Now i want to (re)show the thumbnail when i leave  . So how can i do this ?

HTML :

```
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>

<div id="yt">
    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/sftuxbvGwiU/default.jpg" id="thumb"/>
    <div id="ytplayer"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript :

var player;

```
$("#yt").click(function(){
   $("#thumb").hide();
   player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      height: '90',
      width: '120',
      playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0 },
      videoId: 'sftuxbvGwiU'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your function:

```
$("#yt").click(function(){

   //Here you hide the thumb
   $("#thumb").hide();

   player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      height: '90',
      width: '120',
      playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0 },
      videoId: 'sftuxbvGwiU'
    });
});
```

As you can see, you hide the thumb within your function.

So all we have to do is find out when the video has ended and then show the `#thumb` again:

```
$("#yt").click(function(){
   $("#thumb").hide();
      player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '90',
      width: '120',
      videoId: 'sftuxbvGwiU',
      playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0 },
      events: {
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
}    

function onPlayerStateChange(event,element) {
    //When the video has ended
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {

        //Get the thumb to appear again 
        $("#thumb").show();

        //Optionally, you can also get rid of the player
        element.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

I hope that helped.

Good luck!